# Editing a pop-up window button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm new to css + html and i've been stuck on a simple problem. So I got a popup window from bootstrap, the code is

```
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Contact Us!</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Contact Us</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Contact us at _____</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering how to change the padding of the button, and the color of the text.
I tried using #myModal for the css tag as shown

```
  #myModal{
    background-color: green;
    padding-left:40%;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or You can use inline CSS in:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Contact Us!</button>
```

Like:

```
"<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="color :orange; padding-left:30x;">Contact Us!</button>"
```

This will help i hope.
Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

To change the padding and color you can do this.

Add in CSS

```
.btn btn-info btn-lg{
   color: green;
   padding-left: 30px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to change the button outside of the modal so a simple `.btn` selector will work, so there is no need to select `#myModal`.

The custom stylesheet must be included after the bootstrap declaration for the properties to override;

```
.btn {
  color:green;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNoXMm) here i've added some padding and a custom color so you can see how it works.